# Change color and format of coordinates outside the zoom selector rectangle in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How do I change the color and formatting of these values?

[image]

I want to change the color to black so its visible and I want the X axis to be in a date format. These values appear when right clicking on the graph and selecting an area to zoom into. I am using gnuplot-qt to display the graph

Comment: It is supposed to show up as black when the background is a light color, and white when the background is a dark color.  Apparently something has gone wrong on your setup.  What version of gnuplot and what version of the qt libraries do you have?

Comment: @Ethan I am using 'gnuplot version 5.4 patchlevel 4' and Qt version 5.15.5

Comment: @Ethan I also can't get white text on a dark background neither in wxt nor in qt terminal. gnuplot 5.4.5, Qt 5.16.6.0. Text is always black. Would/should it matter whether the background is a background (e.g. like you can set in wxt terminal) or an object or a curve? Is it maybe again a Windows specific issue?